# How long can my post be locked pending resolution?

Tags: support, specific-question

Several hours ago, a [post of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/434125/13675) was locked.

> locked by **[Alex Becker](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8173/alex-becker)**♦ 8 hours ago
>
> This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info [visit meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/).

This message does not say, however, that right before it was locked, the post was also reverted to a much earlier version, and IMO its most objectionable one (due to content not written by me).

I've been trying to find out the justification for this reversion, without success.  Following the instructions given in the message, I "visited" meta, though it's still not clear to me how such "visiting" is to give me any "info" on why the message was reverted and locked immediately after.  At any rate, I posted the [question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10149/13675) of why the post was reverted, but got no answers.

I don't understand why the resolution of this lock is taking this long.  How long is such a resolution supposed to take?  Can a post be locked indefinitely?  Can I appeal the decision to revert the post to the version I find most objectionable?

Comment: Err... Perhaps a bit more patience is called for? Your other meta question is a mere 9 hours old.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: as I alluded to, I'm still trying to understand what the "for more info visit meta" phrase means...

Comment: As far as I can tell the only content in your post not written by you is the reference I added to point to the original source of the Kratzer quotation that your question contained. Why do you find this objectionable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locks come with four predefined lengths:

- 1 hour (default)
- 1 week
- 1 month
- permanent

A moderator can unlock a post at any time.

The lock is usually left in place until the matter is settled, and the moderators don't expect the problematic behaviour that led to the locking to continue.

You can appeal the decision by a meta post, which you did. Alternatively you can mail to team@stackexchange.com if you are not satisfied by the moderator response and want the SE team to review the decision.